# Autofac AsImplementedInterfaces fails to resolve dependencies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac, ioc-container

This is a big mystery for me. From time to time (can't find a pattern yet) autofac fail when tries to resolve dependencies, here's error message:

> None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'IsThereAnyNews.Mvc.Controllers.HomeController' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
>   Cannot resolve parameter 'IsThereAnyNews.DataAccess.IRssChannelsRepository rssRepository' of constructor 'Void .ctor(IsThereAnyNews.Services.IUserAuthentication, IsThereAnyNews.Services.ILoginService, IsThereAnyNews.Services.ISessionProvider, IsThereAnyNews.DataAccess.IRssChannelsRepository)'.

Here's how I wire the autofac

```
    public static void RegisterDependencies()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();
        // other registrations goes here

        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
    }
```

Project setup is done like this:

```
ASP.MVC

-> Interfaces (where needed)

-> Autofac

      -> Interface

      -> Implementations (*Repository, *Services)
```

Yet for some mystical (for me) reason my face is being slapped with this error. Can anyone explain it to me, what am I doing wrong

**EDIT**
Here's implementation of RssChannelsRepository

```
public class RssChannelsRepository : IRssChannelsRepository
{
    private readonly ItanDatabaseContext database;

    public RssChannelsRepository(ItanDatabaseContext database)
    {
        this.database = database;
    }
}
```

Where ItanDatabaseContext is registered like this:

```
            builder.RegisterType<ItanDatabaseContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Can't tell if stuff are loaded, currently Im facing that issue on azure. For me that happens when I do some debug session, change piece of code here-and-there and do incremental build. Then this issue appears, but not always. To solve it I simple run full rebuild and that's it.

Comment: What does the class declaration for the implementation of `IRssChannelsRepository` look like? And are you sure the assembly containing it is being loaded (i.e. at least one hard reference to a type in it)?

Comment: Updated the questions with class example

Comment: [Why aren’t my assemblies getting scanned after IIS restart?](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/faq/iis-restart.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem might be caused by the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` call. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies(v=vs.110).aspx) the method:

> Gets the assemblies that have been loaded into the execution context of this application domain.

If an assembly isn't loaded yet, it won't be returned from the list. Since your bootstrap code runs very early during application startup, it is possible that no method has been JITted that statically depends on a type in the assembly that contains your repository. If this is the case, that assembly won't be loaded yet and won't be returned from the `GetAssemblies()` method causing the registration to be absent from Autofac.

To make sure that all assemblies are loaded in a deterministic way, you should call [BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildmanager.getreferencedassemblies(v=vs.110).aspx). For instance:

```
public static void RegisterDependencies()
{
    BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies();

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
        .AsImplementedInterfaces();

    // ...
}
```

It's even more efficient to use the assemblies returned from `GetReferencedAssemblies` as input for Autofac, since `AppDomain.GetAssemblies()` would return all `System.*` assemblies as well, which will cause Autofac to go through them as well. For instance:

```
public static void RegisterDependencies()
{
    var assemblies = BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>().ToArray();

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
        .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
        .AsImplementedInterfaces();

    // ...
}
```

This all is [described in more detail](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/faq/iis-restart.html) in the Autofac documentation.

Comment: Looks like this is it, survived couple of iis restarts and resolving like a charm. Thank you.